# How to get rid of spoiling shape of icons when a designer try to make it smaller size?

Tags: shapes, resize, adobe-xd

As shown in the following screen capture, some of the shapes in the icon are being spoiled when I try to resize it. How to get rid of such problem?

[image: showing the icon got rough shape]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE.  How was the icon constructed?  Are there path effects? Is the graphic grouped or not? What scale transform settings are you using? Can you maybe share the file?  I noticed you tagged this with Illustrator, but your screen capture seems to be for AdobeXD.

Comment: @BillyKerr, the icon was constructed using illustrator. first of all I created WiFi icon and then on top of that, I created ellipse. I do not know about scale transformation as a naive designer. How can I share the file please? Yes, I am using this icon in adobe XD and there need to be scaled down as there is less space.

Comment: You can share a file using Dropbox, Adobe Cloud or similar file sharing applications, and post the link here.

Comment: @BillyKerr: the file is uploaded here https://shared-assets.adobe.com/link/cca883c1-7b17-49eb-7699-44cffbe750b6

Comment: I can't get to the file unfortunately, all I see is the rotating loading icon.  Try SVGshare, it's free, no login required.

Comment: Sorry for inconvience, @BillyKerr Kerr. Here is the file with the help of SVGshare: https://svgshare.com/i/L4s.svg

Comment: OK, I've added an answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two ways you could do it. Import the SVG into XD, and do one of the following.

1. Group it using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>, then click and drag to rescale

or alternatively

2. Hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd> as you click and drag to rescale it

I tested these on your file and they work.

I also notice the circle under the WIFI waves is a path, and not an ellipse like the others. This seems to cause a bit of a problem when rescaling as the stroke rescales differently from the other ellipses. Perhaps you could replace that with an ellipse.

If you don't want any of the strokes to rescale when scaling up or down in XD, then when you made it in Illustrator you could have Expanded the strokes, and then grouped everything, before exporting the SVG.

Comment: thank you, @Billy Kerr. :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this shape group was made with some sort of resize constraints on it.
I would suggest to ungroup > remove those constraints > and regroup

also in most cases you can hold shift while resizing with the mouse to scale down proportionally.

more on adobe xd constraints [here](https://helpx.adobe.com/il_en/xd/help/using-responsive-resize.html)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using responsive resize. in some of the elements. Select the object, check on the sidebar if "Responsive Resize" is enabled and disable it. If it doesn't solve, some of the inner groups might have it enabled.

Alternatively, ungroup the whole thing and re-group again, making sure to not enable Responsive Resize again.